# Unexpected masked element in numpy's isin() with masked arrays. Bug?

Tags: python, numpy, masked-array

Using numpy and the following masked arrays

```
import numpy.ma as ma
a = ma.MaskedArray([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], [[True,False,False],[False,False,False]])
ta = ma.array([1,4,5])
```

```
>>> a
masked_array(
  data=[[--, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]],
  mask=[[ True, False, False],
        [False, False, False]],
  fill_value=999999)
>>> ta
masked_array(data=[1, 4, 5],
             mask=False,
       fill_value=999999)
```

to check for each element in `a` if it is in `ta`, I use

```
ma.isin(a, ta)
```

This command gives

```py
masked_array(
  data=[[False, False, False],
        [True, True, --]],
  mask=[[False, False, False],
        [False, False,  True]],
  fill_value=True)
```

Why is the last element in the result masked? Neither of the input arrays is masked at this point.

Using the the standard numpy version produces to be expected results:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.isin(a, ta)
array([[ True, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False]])
```

Here, however, the very first element is `True` because the mask of `a` was ignored.

Tested with Python 3.9.4 and numpy 1.20.3.

Comment: It does indeed look buggy.  Compare the `np` and `ma` versions of the reverse (`isin(ta,a)`).

Comment: `isin(t1,a)` should produce a shape like `ta`, but it returns a `a` shape.  `np.isin` returns the correct shape.  `ma` was added early on, but I don't think it gets a lot of use, and this `isin` (or `in1d`) probably gets even less.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for your test. `ma.isin(ta,a)` gives me the correct output, having the shape of `ta`.

Comment: I misread the output of `ma.isin(ta,a)`.  Size is right.

Comment: I think I tracked down the error, and possible fix to `ma.in1d`.  It concatenates `a` and `ta`, and then sorts.  But how should the sort handle the masked `1`?  Keep it as the start with the `1` from `ta`, or move it to the end where '--' belongs.  There's some ambiguity as to how the masked values should be tested.

Comment: If you really need to do this, consider doing `np.isin(a.data, ta.data)`, and then make a masked array from this boolean and `a.mask`.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks again! Let's open an issue on numpy's github. I am happy to do that, I just don't want to take the credit for your analysis. So if you want to do that, please do, otherwise I can do it.

Comment: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/19877